# Count down a column until value in column meets condition

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a simple daily rainfall data set and would like to calculate the antecedent dry period for each day. Here, I'm defining a dry day to be "<10". I'm fairly unfamiliar with INDEX(), MATCH(), and other fancy array functions but feel like I'll need to use them.

[image: rainfall data set]

For example, in the image, for 1/17/2020, the values in cells `C3:C9=0, C10=1, C11:C13=0`. I've tried various versions of `COUNTIF()`, `COUNTIFS()`, and `IF()` functions but I cannot get the step-wise + re-set functionality necessary when extended "dry spells" or brief rain periods occur with gaps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need to use Match. Basically you need to search for the next antecedent wet day (of which there are many here in Manchester England at the moment) and subtract 1 (Formula 1):

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B15:B$1000>=10,0),0)-1
```

where B$1000 may need changing to include all of your data. The use of Index here is just a bit of a hack to avoid having to enter the formula as an array formula.

[image]

As you can see there is an issue when you come to the end of the range which I will come to in a minute.

In this case, we want to count the number of antecedent dry days to the end of the range (Formula 2):

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B4:B$1000>=10,0),0)-1,COUNTIF(B4:B$1000,"<10"))
```

[image]

If the range ended with a dry spell, you would get this:

[image]

Comment: This is what I'm looking for exactly. Thanks Tom! Wishing you some dry weather over there in the England.